# how to create a complex object from a Cucumber table?

Tags: java, cucumber

I do not know how to read table from `.feature` and populate correctly

```
| payInstruction.custodian | and | payInstruction.acctnum |
```

like the internal class.

I have a table:

```
  | confirmationId | totalNominal | payInstruction.custodian | payInstruction.acctnum |
  | 1              | 100.1321     | yyy                      | yyy                    |
  | 2              | 100.1351     | zzz                      | zzz                    |
```

and I have class template which has the next structure:

```
class Confirmation {
String confirmationId;
double totalNominal;
PayInstruction payInstruction;

}

class PayInstruction  {
String custodian;
String acctnum;
}
```

auto converting table to `List<Confirmation>` has error because cannot recognize `payInstruction.acctnum` and pay `payInstruction.custodian`

any help ?

Comment: Have you got the scenario for this table? And have you ran Cucumber yet to generate the test cases for this?

Comment: px06 - yes, and had cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No such field integration.cucumber.template.Confirmation.payInstruction.custodian

Comment: Cucumber will only automatically convert for primitive properties on your desired class. You will have to manually convert to include the PayInstruction part...

Comment: Grasshopper - yes, sure I am ready, but problem is need to find way and maybe add some listener somewhere which will call when Cucumber will compare name of header with Class field, I only find out Converter.class but  the Converter provide restricted logic? look like its not applicable for my case

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is a bit old, but Google did drive me here and could do so with others in the future.

`.feature` adaptations according to the question :

```
Given some confirmations:
| confirmationId | totalNominal |
| 1              | 100.1321     |
| 2              | 100.1351     |
And some pay instructions:
| confirmationId | custodian | acctnum |
| 1              | yyy       | yyy     |
| 2              | zzz       | zzz     |
```

Steps implementation :

```
Map<Integer, Confirmation> confirmations;

@Given('^some confirmations:$)
public void someConfirmations(List<Confirmation> confirmations) {
  this.confirmations = confirmations.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Confirmation::getConfirmationId, Function.identity()));
}

@And('^some pay instructions:$)
public void somePayInstructions(List<PayInstructionTestObject> payInstructions) {
  payInstructions.forEach(pi -> 
    this.confirmations.get(pi.getConfirmationId()).addPayInstruction(pi.toPayInstruction())
  );
}
```

The trick is to create a sub class of PayInstruction **in test folder** which holds a confirmation id as correlation identifier to retrieve the correct confirmation. The `toPayInstruction` method serves as converter to get rid of the test object.

Hope the Java and feature code is almost compiling, I'm writing this without effectively making it run. Slight adaptations might be necessary to make it run.

The original business model was untouched by the solution, not breaking / tweaking it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to supply the constructor for `Confirmation` with four primitives and then create the `PayInstruction` in the constructor of `Confirmation`.

Comment: It breaks the abstraction of the domain concepts. Not fine.